# Bootstrap's multiple selectpicker using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-select

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm trying to implement Silvio Moreto's [bootstrap-select plugin](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) in my web-page. I would really appreciate any help.

My Rails version is 4.0.4, and I'm using turbolinks-2.5.3

I already have everything I need installed, but I don't know how to embed my current .erb code into the syntax needed for the selectpicker multiple class to work.

Additionally, I have some other style classes I need to maintain so my page layout remains formatted the way it is.

Here is an example on how the selectpicker should be implemented:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

and this is the part of my code I want to implement it on. It already works, but the styling looks horrible:

```
<%= select_tag :portafolio_id,
                  options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.portafolios, :id, :nombre,
                  params[:portafolio_id]), 
                  multiple: true, size: '8%', class: "form-control input-sm "%>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm selectpicker" id="portafolio_id" multiple="multiple" name="portafolio_id[]" size="8">
<option value="68">ABC</option>
<option value="11">Demo 1</option>
<option value="66">Demo 2</option>
<option value="185">MEXICO</option>
<option value="106">Peru</option>
<option value="184">Peru gob</option>
<option value="585">prueba</option>
<option value="961">temp-h0zul</option>
</select>
```

This is the code for the empty drop-down menu generated on top of the select-tag, which is far more incomprehensible (to me, at least):

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick form-control input-sm">
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle form-control selectpicker btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="portafolio_id" title="Nothing selected">
<span class="filter-option pull-left">Nothing selected</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret">
</span>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu open">
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
<li data-original-index="0">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>
ABC</span>">
<span class="text">ABC</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="1">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>
Demo 1</span>">
<span class="text">Demo 1</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="2">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Demo 2</span>">
<span class="text">Demo 2</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="3">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>MEXICO</span>">
<span class="text">MEXICO</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="4">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Peru</span>">
<span class="text">Peru</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="5">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>Peru gob</span>">
<span class="text">Peru gob</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="6">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>prueba</span>">
<span class="text">prueba</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li data-original-index="7">
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>temp-h0zul</span>">
<span class="text">temp-h0zul</span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you inspect the select tag html and paste the output in the question?

Comment: Sure! Is this what you need?

Comment: yeah! whats the output if you add selectpicker class to the select_tag's class: ?

Comment: This is far more confusing, but I'll paste it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `selectpicker` to the class of the select_tag

```
<%= select_tag :portafolio_id,
  options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.portafolios, :id, :nombre,
  params[:portafolio_id]), 
  multiple: true, size: '8%', class: "form-control input-sm selectpicker"%>
```

I also use this javascript to reactivate selectpicker in case you use turbolinks

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $('*:not(.bootstrap-select) > .selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

*Note that the callback should be instead `ready turbolinks:load` for users of turblinks 5+*

Also, make sure you have

```
//= require bootstrap-select
```

In your application.js, it should come after bootstrap/jquery

Comment: Where should I put the javascript? Right now I placed it in my application.js file and it is not working. :(

Comment: Can you edit your question to add your version of Rails, and if you are using turbolinks at all ? `bundle show turbolinks`. The javascript should be in application.js anyway, but if you use turbolinks you might need to wrap it in an event callback

Comment: Updates my answer. Also make sure there are no javascript errors.